# flywaydb applies java migrations even when SQLException is raised

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, flyway

I want to use flywaydb in order to to version control my database and manage Database schema and data migrations. I want to use the java migrations and java api because I think it's easier to integrate it inside my app. The problem is that when I applied my migrations although I had a syntax error on my sql prepared statment and raised an SQLException the metadata table of flywaydb (schema_version) contained the record that my migrations was applied. Is there a way to change this behavour? My java migration class implements JdbcMigration

```
public class V1_2__Change_commnets_to_int implements JdbcMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Connection con){
        PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement("Query with syntax error");
        try{
            stm.execute();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            stm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you also please provide with an example of how to use checksums with java migrations in flywaydb?

Answer (score 0):

Your code caught the exception and carried on, so Flyway didn't know there was anything wrong.

Better to rethrow it

```
catch(SQLException e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```